# JSLint: cross reference across functions

Tags: javascript, jslint

I am not sure how to solve this issue. Lets assume we have two functions like this:

JSLint will complain that `rebind_test2();` is not defined before it is accessed. And if I move `rebind_test2()` above the first function, it will complain again that `rebind_test1();` is not defined before its accessed. Is there a solution to this?

```
function rebind_test1(){
    "use strict";
    $('#row').load('test/', function(result){
        rebind_test2();
    });    
}

function rebind_test2(){
    "use strict";
    var i = 1;
    rebind_test1();
}
```

Comment: This is quite an annoying warning; I don't think either of the answers are ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@torazaburo's answer will work, and alternatively you can just pretend that the function declared second is "global" (as if it was declared in a different file):

```
/*global rebind_test2 */
```

Comment: Thanks, true that would work as well, but it is actually declared in the same file. ;) hence torazaburo might be the real solution?

Comment: @Kave - It depends if you want to change your code, or just add the global directive. Neither is ideal... go with whichever you feel most comfortable with!

Comment: This solution seems actually easier. Less need to refactor +1

Answer (score 2):

```
var rebind_test2;

function rebind_test1(){
    "use strict";
    $('#row').load('test/', function(result){
        rebind_test2();
    });    
}

rebind_test2=function(){
    "use strict";
    var i = 1;
    rebind_test1();
}
```

Comment: +1 seems to be working. :) I leave it a bit open to see if there are other ideas as well. Thanks